# JQuery adding location.hash is endless refreshing Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

This script below is working with IE9 and Chrome 18, but is causing endless refreshing on Firefox 11.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    if (window.location.href.indexOf('#') == -1) {
        window.location.hash = 'Value';
        //window.location.href += 'Value';
    }
});
</script>
```

Best Regards,

Leszek

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that changing the hash causes document.ready again on firefox. The script sees that the href has no hash symbol in it, and changes it again. Presto, infinite loop. I would use this code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if (window.location.hash.length == 0) {
        window.location.hash = '#Value';
    }
});
```